# DropDown Issue in html

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create FAQ by which click on Arrow I will display answer. I am making by using this link.

[W3CSchollLink](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryit.asp?filename=tryw3css_accordion)

Can any body suggest me how can I get these cls so I can modify and How I can put arrow.

Cls are `w3-btn w3-block w3-black w3-left-align` and `w3-container w3-hide` also i want to put arrow.

My Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>W3.CSS</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<body>
<div class="w3-container">
<button onclick="myFunction('Demo1')" class="w3-btn w3-block w3-black w3-left-align">Open Section 1</button>
<div id="Demo1" class="w3-container w3-hide">
  <h4>Section 1</h4>
  <p>Some text..</p>
</div>

</div>
<script>
function myFunction(id) {
    var x = document.getElementById(id);
    if (x.className.indexOf("w3-show") == -1) {
        x.className += " w3-show";
    } else { 
        x.className = x.className.replace(" w3-show", "");
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Give background image for h4 tag and you can change the arrow with the help of w3-show and we-hide classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Hope this will help you :)

```js
function myFunction(id) {
  var x = document.getElementById(id);
  if (x.className.indexOf("w3-show") == -1) {
    x.className += " w3-show";
  } else {
    x.className = x.className.replace(" w3-show", "");
  }
}
```

```css
.w3-container,
.w3-panel {
  padding: 0.01em 16px;
}

.w3-black,
.w3-hover-black:hover {
  color: #fff!important;
  background-color: #000!important;
}

.w3-block {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.w3-btn,
.w3-button {
  border: none;
  display: inline-block;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
  background-color: inherit;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.w3-btn,
.w3-button {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.w3-block {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.w3-left-align {
  text-align: left!important;
}

.w3-hide {
  display: none;
}

.w3-show-block,
.w3-show {
  display: block!important;
}

.w3-btn:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

.FAQ1 {
  position: relative;
}

.FAQ1 :before {
  content: '';
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 9px;
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/3R9OU.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="w3-container">
  <div class="FAQ1">

    <button onclick="myFunction('Demo1')" class="w3-btn w3-block w3-black w3-left-align">Open Section 1</button>

    <div id="Demo1" class="w3-container w3-hide">
      <h4>Section 1</h4>
      <p>Some text..</p>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: This was exactly what I wanted. Thanks :)

Comment: Even I also now got how to take css from there :)

Comment: Do you want any explanation how arrow image is being used?

Comment: By using background image ?.. Would love if you explain .. :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a bit simplistic, but I think this is what you are searching for?

```css
#arrow {
  float: right;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>W3.CSS</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<body>
<div class="w3-container">
<button class="w3-btn w3-block w3-teal w3-left-align">Open Section 1<img id="arrow" src="http://golfergroups.com/img/arr.png" alt="arrow" onclick="myFunction('Demo1')" ></button>
<div id="Demo1" class="w3-container w3-hide">
  <h4>Section 1</h4>
  <p>Some text..</p>
</div>
<script>
function myFunction(id) {
    var x = document.getElementById(id);
    if (x.className.indexOf("w3-show") == -1) {
        x.className += " w3-show";
    } else { 
        x.className = x.className.replace(" w3-show", "");
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

In case it's not working or if this is not what you're looking for, let me know.